# Android WebView not loading captcha image from https website

Tags: android, ssl, browser, webview

I am developing an Android application which requires me to load a third-party website `https://mmmoffice.com/`. I am using webview to load this URL and the problem i'm facing is that, the captcha image from this webpage is not showing. If i open the same URL from the normal android browser, or google chrome browser, or firefox browser or UC browser, they all work well and the captcha image is shown. But its not showing in my webview. Please i need help.
I have read lots of article on stackoverflow and google, but none helped. Below is my code:

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webMain);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("https://mmmoffice.com");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I create a project with your code to check your issue. You are getting

```
 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(3)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of null", source: https://ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=088620b277/cloudflare.min.js (3)
 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null", source: https://mmmoffice.com/js/storage.js?v=1 (5)
```

When webview is trying to load captcha.

Just add `settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);`. Your final code should looks like:

```
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://mmmoffice.com/");
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Not working, still it says "Please upgrade your browser"